# Meaning of "declining" in "The land declines sharply away from the house"

Tags: meaning

Whilst studying the expression "declining" I came across the following explanation:

*[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/decline)* : declining = to gradually become less, worse, or lower:

Basically, I recognised the meaning of the word, but there is also a sentence
I don't understand as follows:

**Formal: The land declines sharply away from the house**

I have no idea what this means.

On another search by google I have found a sentence similar to it:

**A Compendium of Modern Husbandry:** 
*[Compose a good soil](https://books.google.de/books?id=UX9aAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA265&lpg=PA265&dq=The%20land%20declines%20sharply%20away%20from%20the%20house&source=bl&ots=PwklsAnUTN&sig=wO3-ooMOk1gq_DedfLABtaDzZec&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2_6iOpMHZAhVoCsAKHSr0C-EQ6AEIUjAF#v=onepage&q&f=false)*; the situation and formation of this land was such, that the kitchen garden could not where be placed but at the back front of the house, and as the land declined very rapidly, I proposed to sink the ground so low...

Comment: Look at your definition more closely: "to gradually become ***lower***".  The land slopes down as you go away from the house.

Comment: An _incline_ goes up from the speaker; _decline_ is the opposite. A more common expression would be _slopes down_.

Comment: So it describes the level of the ground surrounding the house, and sharply means, direcly from outside the walls ?

Comment: But it's bad writing because it's confusing. I would have used a physical term like _slopes down_ to be clear.

Comment: Does "sharply" perhaps mean the angle of declination ?

Comment: Is it a rule to vote down before the answer is questioned ?  For me it's still unclear what" declining sharply away" means.

Comment: Yes, the ground slopes sharply, i.e. at a greater angle, than sloping gently.

Comment: Sorry when the question does not fit in your favorite themes

Comment: ok, now i have a better picture of it :-) I remember of reading "sharp" in other context.  But it still draws the picture of 90 degree everytime :-)

Comment: What @John said. Because ***to decline*** is usually used "figuratively" (as in *to become lower **quality***, not lower elevation), I might well understand OP's cited text as meaning the soil is **less fertile** further away from the house (perhaps for lack of irrigation / manure / etc.).

Comment: One or two of your older [questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/157618/questions-with-what-followed-by-a-an) have been migrated to ELL, you should join the community. It's easy, just visit the site and click on the button which invites you to become a member.

Comment: some of you :-)

Answer (score 0):

This "decline" is referring to the angle of depression formed by the house and the land, which is further elaborated as "sharp". The angle of depression is referred to as a sight line, so it means that if your eyes were at ground level of the house, you would have to look down to follow the path of the land. In the picture at the bottom, you can see these relationships, and the "decline" in the sentence refers to the sight line, while sharply shows that the angle of depression is relatively [high](http://www.mathwords.com/a/a_assets/angle%20of%20depression.gif)

.

Comment: Only out of  interest and referring to the picture, what would be the sharpest depression/declination ?  For example something over zero degree,  0.01 degrees ?